# Describing response object in API-Explorer/Swagger

Tags: php, restler, swagger

I'm using [Restler 3's API-Explorer](https://github.com/Skookum/SwaggerToMarkdown) which is a fork of [Swagger-UI](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui) and am wondering if anyone has found an effective way of documenting/describing the response JSON object that the API returns. Obviously some of this -- in a "read between the lines" sort of way -- is available when you interactively try out the API but I'd like some way of indicating more verbosely the structure of the response. Has anyone come up with anything for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do that with the `@return` PHPDoc comment.

For an example, take a look at the [Rate Limiting Example](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_009_rate_limiting/readme.html) in the [explorer](http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_009_rate_limiting/explorer/index.html#!/authors-v1/v1-authors-_id-_get) for

```
GET authors.json/{id}
```

you will find **Response Information** listing

```
Author ( name: string, email: string )
```

It is coming from the following class set as the return type

```
<?php
/**
 * Dummy class, used only for creating swagger spec model (json schema)
 * look at the generated resources json to understand
 */
class Author
{
    public $name='Name';
    public $email='name@domain.com';
}
```

Comment: Great example. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: For some reason my own version is not exposing the response information (it's also not showing the variables type info). Probably something screwed up on my end. Any ideas?

Comment: btw, I have the latest git version from your "master" branch of Restler-API-Explorer (0d79cd8). I am a bit of a newbie to git though and since I forked it and kept reference to your repository via a remote of "upstream" I'm a little worried I did something stupid when I merged my changes in. My changes were VERY basic.

Comment: I will check it out, meanwhile use the explorer that comes with the examples

Comment: Yes I came to that idea last night and it does improve things but it's not perfect ... types show up but they are all listed as "string" and the JSON pre-fill of the BODY variables is not happening.

Comment: In the lastest version, I don't find that `@return Author` is sufficient; however

    `@return Author {@type Author}`

seems to lead to the desired result